What is the dimension of the following vector space?
I want to find the dimension of quotient
$$
V = \mathbb{R}^{2}{\LARGE /}\left\{\begin{pmatrix} \phantom{-}x\\-x\end{pmatrix} : x \in \mathbb{R}\right\}.
$$
It feels like the dimension is $2$ but I am not sure how to prove that it is $2$.

Do you have the rank-nullity theorem?

@CyclotomicField: Yes I do, but how do I use it?

Use the definition of the quotient space to find the dimension of the nullspace. Then apply the theorem.

@CyclotomicField: I see. So turns out the dimension is 1, and I was wrong. Thanks for your help.

$\{(x,-x\}$ is a line in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Therefore, the classes of the quotient are lines parallel to the given one. Your quotient is a space of parallel lines, with only one degree of freedom. So its dimension is $=1$.
